# Use article reference style with book documentclass

Tags: bibtex, document-classes

I have to use a journal's Latex template, which specifies \documentclass{book}. The template assumes I will enter my references manually in the format that they want. However, I would like to use bibtex to enter my references. When I do that, it forces the Bibliography to start on an odd-numbered page. I would like the references to start directly after the end of the article. I have tried changing the documentclass to "article", but that causes errors because the template uses the chapter format. Is there a way to revert back to the article-style references within the book documentclass?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}

\begin{document}

Document contents here with use of \cite.

\renewcommand{\bibname}{References} % to change "Bibliography" to "References"
\bibliography{refs} % starts references on next odd-numbered page
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Add the following lines to the preamble: `\usepackage{etoolbox}

\patchcmd{\thebibliography}
  {\chapter*}
  {\section*}
  {}
  {}`

Comment: Are you loading the `natbib` package?

Comment: I tried this (along with a few permutations), and it still starts the References on the next odd-numbered page. Yes, I am loading the natbib package. Sorry I forget to add that line of code.

Comment: Please see my updated answer below. Since you load `natbib`, you can use the second code in my answer.

Comment: Try adding `openany` to your class options.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are *not* loading `natbib`, you can pacth `\thebibliography` so it uses `\section*` instead of `\chapter*`:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\patchcmd{\thebibliography}
  {\chapter*}
  {\section*}
  {}
  {}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}

% this is just for the example
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{refs.bib}
@article{testa,
  author = {The A Author},
  year = {2014},
  title = {The title A},
  journal = {The journal A},
  pages = {1--5},
}
\end{filecontents*}
% this is just for the example

\begin{document}

\cite{testa}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{refs}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you are loading `natbib`, then all you have to do is to redefine `\bibsection`:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage{natbib}

\renewcommand\bibsection{%
  \section*{\bibname\markright{\MakeUppercase{\bibname}}}}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}

% this is just for the example
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{refs.bib}
@article{testa,
  author = {The A Author},
  year = {2014},
  title = {The title A},
  journal = {The journal A},
  pages = {1--5},
}
\end{filecontents*}
% this is just for the example

\begin{document}

\cite{testa}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{refs}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You are amazing. The second one worked great.

Comment: The second suggestion had one quirk in that it renamed the page heading to "REFERENCES", which I'm sure you knew, but I didn't notice at first. The following gives me the behavior that I want.   \renewcommand\bibsection{\section*{\large References}}. That is entered without the \renewcommand{\bibname}{References} line.

Comment: @user50028 Or simply remove the `\markright` part: `\renewcommand\bibsection{\section*{\bibname}}`.